# Need of setting the flag in a nditer()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

If we want to iterate all the elements stored in an nD-array we can use nditer() but if we want to set the dtype of the elements that are gonna be accessed then we need to set the buffer as well what is the reason for that?

Ex::

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (10,))
for i in np.nditer(a,op_dtypes=['float']):
    print(i,end='\t')
```

The above code will give me an error:

> TypeError: Iterator operand required copying or buffering, but neither copying nor buffering was enabled

It's asking me to set the flag to copying or buffering what is the purpose of setting the flag? and what do the buffering and copying flag do?

Comment: `nditer` doesn't make iteration on elements any easier or faster.  Don't waste time on it.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#iterating-as-a-specific-data-type

Answer (score 0):

You created an integer array:

```
In [16]: a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (10,))   
In [17]: a
Out[17]: array([5, 5, 8, 6, 5, 6, 4, 1, 8, 3])
```

You don't need `nditer` to display it element by element, not even in float form:

```
In [18]: for i in a:
    ...:     print(i,end='\t')
    ...:     
5   5   8   6   5   6   4   1   8   3   

In [19]: for i in a.astype(float):
    ...:     print(i,end='\t')
    ...:     
5.0 5.0 8.0 6.0 5.0 6.0 4.0 1.0 8.0 3.0
```

With the `astype` I made a temporary copy of floats.

I don't why you are exploring `nditer`.  Don't be misled by its claim to be an 'efficient iterator'.  I have yet to see it being faster than the simple `for`.  Even with `nditer` you still have to use `for`.  Generally it's what you do within the loop that takes up the time; the iteration mechanism doesn't matter much.  Doing `print()` 10 times takes up 'x' time regardless of the `for` wrapper.

```
In [20]: for i in np.nditer(a):
    ...:     print(i,end='\t')
    ...:     
5   5   8   6   5   6   4   1   8   3
```

I won't try to time these alternatives, especially not with that io `print` function.

Following the examples in the doc link:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#iterating-as-a-specific-data-type

```
In [23]: for i in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readonly','copy'], op_dtypes=[float]):
    ...:     print(i, end='\t')
    ...:     
5.0 5.0 8.0 6.0 5.0 6.0 4.0 1.0 8.0 3.0
```

Evidently the flags give `nditer` permission to something equivalent to `astype(float)`, whether as temporary array, or on-the-fly buffering.

`np.nditer` is best used as testing ground for the use of `nditer` in compiled code, such as illustrated at the end of the doc page, which uses `cython`.  There it gives fine grained control over iteration and creation of output buffers, etc.  That kind of control is seldom needed when writing normal `numpy` code.

You'll in SO `numpy` questions that we usually advocate using the precompiled array methods.  Think in terms of whole-array operations, and make full use of broadcasting, and `ufuncs`.  Try not to iterate in a list like fashion, and if you must, be prepared to port that to `cython` or `numba` if you need speed.  I have yet to see a `nditer` question from an experienced user.

When you iterate as in `for i in a:...`, the `i` will be a `numpy scalar`, in this case `np.int32`.  With `nditer`, the `i` will be a 0d array (with that same dtype).  The difference is subtle, but can be important.  In my opinion, `nditer` usually adds more complications than needed.